# Null check operator used on a null value when checking with if

Tags: flutter, dart

Whenever I go on my login page, I get the error that I used null check operator on a null value, it only happens when there is no login/password entered before. In init state I am checking with `isNotEmpty`, so why am I getting this error? How can I fix it?

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
```

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    UserPreferences.init().then((_) {
      if (UserPreferences.getEmail!.isNotEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          _isChecked = true;
          _email.text = UserPreferences.getEmail!;
          _password.text = UserPreferences.getPassword!;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

```dart
class UserPreferences {
  static SharedPreferences? _preferences;

  static Future<void> init() async {
    _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  static setEmail(String username) async {
    await _preferences?.setString('email', username);
  }

  static setPassword(String password) async {
    await _preferences?.setString('password', password);
  }

  static String? get getEmail => _preferences?.getString('email');
  static String? get getPassword => _preferences?.getString('password');
}
```

Comment: This approach is not recommended since share preferences package does not encrypt the data. But what I recommend you is to initialize the _prefs.setString('email', '0') with some value for it not to be null when initializing.

Comment: @WilsonToribio then in my email input I will have '0' which I do not want

Comment: `if (UserPreferences.getEmail!.isNotEmpty) {` asserts that `UserPreferences.getEmail` is not `null` (which might not necessarily be true) before calling the `isNotEmpty` getter.  Furthermore, `isNotEmpty` has nothing to do with checking for `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, using a `!` in null checks means your code has bugs. If it didn't have bugs, you would not need this operator.

The `!` operator only forces your compiler to go through with what you programmed, even though it *knows* it could be wrong. It warned you, but you decided that instead of listening to your compiler, you just told it to shut up (by using operator `!`). If you want to write good code, just forget the operator `!` for null checks ever existed.

```
final previousEmail = UserPreferences.getEmail;
final previousPassword = UserPreferences.getPassword;

if (previousEmail != null) {
    setState(() {
      _isChecked = true;
      _email.text = previousEmail;

      if(previousPassword != null) {
          _password.text = previousPassword;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this null check operator has caused many errors in my app. I'll just forget about it

Answer (score 0):

Call this `init` inside FutureBuilder then check the Condition for non being empty. Because `initState` is not for Initializing the Async Function.